# Reactjs :TypeError: rows.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I m trying to fetch posts and users data from API ,on fetching posts data I m getting following error :-

`TypeError: rows.map is not a function`

The above error occurred in the  component.

Here is TableView.js:-

```
import React from 'react';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';


class TableView extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const {rows,columns}= this.props;
        return(
            <Paper>
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {columns?
                                columns.map((col,i) =>{
                                    return(
                                        <TableCell key={i}>
                                            {col.label}
                                        </TableCell>
                                    )
                                })
                            :null
                        }
                        </TableRow>

                    </TableHead>

                    <TableBody>
                        {rows ?
                        rows.map((row,i)=>{
                            return columns.map((col,colIndex) =>{
                                return(
                                    <TableCell>
                                        {row[col.name]}
                                    </TableCell>
                                )
                                
                            })
                            
                            
                        })
                        :null}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </Paper>
        )
        
    }
}

export default TableView;
```

Here is Posts.js:-

```
import React from 'react';
import TableView from '../../Common/TableView';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as AdminActions from '../../../store/actions/adminActions';

const columns=[
    {label:'ID',name:'id'},
    {label:'Title',name:"title"},
    
]

class Posts extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getPosts(this.props.auth.token);
    }
    render(){
        const posts = this.props.admin.posts;
        return(
            <div>
                  <h1>Posts page</h1>
                <TableView
                columns={columns}
                rows={Posts}
                />
              
            </div>

            
        )
            
        
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state=>{
    return{
        auth:state.auth,
        admin: state.admin
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
        getPosts:(token)=>{
            dispatch(AdminActions.getPosts(token));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Posts);
```

Here is api.js:-

```
import axios from 'axios';

const host= 'http://localhost:8080';
const API={

 login:  (email,pass,success)=>{
     axios.post(`${host}/api/users/login`,{email:email , password:pass})
     .then(res =>{success(res);
    });

 },
  getUsers:(token,success) =>{
      axios.get(`${host}/api/users?access_token=${token}`)
      .then(res =>{
          success(res);
      })
  },
  getPosts:(token,success)=>{
      axios.get(`${host}/api/POSTs?access_token=${token}`)
      .then( res=>{
          success(res);
      })
  }

}

export default API;
```

here is app.js:-

```
import React from 'react';
import PageWrapper from "./components/PageWrapper";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

//PAGES
import Home from "./components/Pages/Home.js";
import About from "./components/Pages/About.js";
import Contact from "./components/Pages/Contact.js";
import Login from "./components/Pages/Login.js";

//Admin pages
import Dashboard from './components/Pages/Admin/Dashboard';
import Users from './components/Pages/Admin/Users';
import Posts from './components/Pages/Admin/Posts';

import AdminWrapper from "./components/AdminWrapper.js"
import LoginWrapper from "./components/LoginWrapper.js";


class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
  return (
    <div>
    
    <Router>
<Route 
path='/admin/users'
render={props =>{
  return(
  <div>
      {this.props.auth.token ?
        <AdminWrapper>
      <Users/>
      </AdminWrapper>
        : 
        <LoginWrapper>
           <Login/>
        </LoginWrapper>
       
      }
        
      </div>     
)}
  }

 />

<Route 
path='/admin/posts'
render={props =>{
  return(
  <div>
      {this.props.auth.token ?
        <AdminWrapper>
      <Posts />
      </AdminWrapper>
        : 
        <LoginWrapper>
           <Login/>
        </LoginWrapper>
       
      }
        
      </div>     
)}
  }

/>



      <Route
      exact={true}
      path='/admin'
      render={props =>{
        return(
        <div>
            {this.props.auth.token ?
              <AdminWrapper>
            <Dashboard/>
            </AdminWrapper>
              : 
              <LoginWrapper>
                 <Login/>
              </LoginWrapper>
             
            }
              
            </div>     
      )}
        }
      
      />
    
    
          
            <Route exact={true} path="/"
            render={props =>(
              <PageWrapper>
                <Home {...props} />
              </PageWrapper>
            )}
            ></Route>

            <Route
            path="/about"
            render={props =>(
              <PageWrapper>
                <About {...props} />
              </PageWrapper>
            )}
            />
            <Route
            path="/contact"
            render={props =>(
              <PageWrapper>
                <Contact {...props} />
              </PageWrapper>
            )}
            />
            
      
      </Router>
      </div>
  );
}
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>{
  return{
    auth:state.auth
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  return{

  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

here is adminReducers.js:-

```
const defaultState={
    users:[],
    posts:[]
}

const admin=(state = defaultState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'GOT USERS':
            return{
                ...state,
                users: action.payload
            }
            case 'GOT_POSTS':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    posts: action.payload
                }
            default:
                return state
    }
}

export default admin;
```

here is  adminactions.js :-

```
import API from '../../utils/api';

export const getUsers=(token) =>{
    return dispatch =>{
        API.getUsers(token,res =>{
        
            dispatch({
                type:'GOT USERS',
                payload:res.data
            })
        })
    }

}

export const getPosts =(token)=>{
    return dispatch =>{
        API.getPosts(token,res =>{
            dispatch({
                type:'GOT_POSTS',
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Pardon me if am unable to fully explain the problem am facing, but after google searching, I came to understand that the object am trying to map is not an array(which am not sure is the case this time around because, all the examples I see online is the same and I take my time for the past 4weeks to diligently follow up the examples I see online but I cant just figure my react app to work

Comment: where is your admin reducer? it should have a posts array in it's state.

Comment: @Vahid18u   I have added the adminReducers and also  adminactions. Let me know if it is helpful to you :)

Comment: {rows?.length ?
                        rows.map((row,i)=>{
                            return columns.map((col,colIndex) =>{
                                return(
                                    <TableCell>
                                        {row[col.name]}
                                    </TableCell>
                                )
                                
                            })
                            
                            
                        })
                        :null}

Can you try this and check if it works.

Comment: in adminactions.js, before dispatching GOT_POSTS, check if res.data is a real array by logging it.

Comment: @ShubhamJajoo thanks it worked :) but can you explain me why it worked

Comment: @ShagunRaghav, its async operation, and it will take some time to update the store. And you have applied `map()` on rows, when it was not even updated. So it was breaking there. I just applied check for array length and then only I am mapping over it. :)!